# An underdetermined linear system for GPS (2)

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently trying to solve a math problem about the Global Positioning System.
At the top of page 388 it says:

> The quadratic terms in all the equations are the same, so by subtracting the first equation from each of the other three, we obtain a system of three linear equations:

It might be because of my lack of English, but I cannot seem to understand the logic behind it.

http://mathdl.maa.org/images/upload_library/22/Polya/Kalman.pdf

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

He ends up with three linear (affine) equations in four variables, which means three can be expressed in terms of one variable (ie, there is just one parameter). Then use one of the original quadratic equations and replace all variables by their function of the parameter. Then you have a quadratic in one parameter.